# iTunes deciding not to update podcasts

Tags: itunes, windows

iTunes, trying to be helpful, automatically stops updating my podcasts when it thinks I've not listened to them recently enough. It's quite maddening!

[image: iTunes has stopped updating this podcast]

How can I turn off this "helpful" feature?

Comment: I've googled this and not found any good workaround, I'd love to see a permanent hack that kills this 'feature'.